# Code for Multiple Sheet/Active Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

i'm currently working on a code that will copy data from one sheet to another (please see below),it currently works on one sheet, but now I want this code to work on multiple sheets or whatever sheet is active. Can you please assist me in modifying this code to work on multiple sheets.

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A15:E188").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A15").Select

Sheets("FCI").Select
Range("C51").Select

'Copy the data
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
'Activate the destination worksheet
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
'Select the target range
Range("A15").Select
'Paste in the target destination
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: just remove the 2nd line `Sheets("Sheet1").Select`. code will copy data from whatever sheet is active and paste it in Sheet1.

Comment: What worksheet are you copying the cells from and its destination? Are the ranges fixed or dynamic?

Comment: @MaddyNikam The second line is set to indicate that any existing data that's on "Sheet1" should be deleted, shouldn't I remove the 6th line perhaps, because that's the sheet indicated to take the data from.

Comment: @RomcelGeluz, The ranges are dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this is what you are looking for, also you can yourself twick the code little bit to suit your requirements.

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()

temp = ActiveSheet.Index

Sheets(temp).Select
Range("A15:E188").Copy

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
k = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A" & k + 1).Select ' kindly change the code to suit your paste location
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

modified your code with a loop to go through all the sheets present in workbook.
let me know if this is what was required.

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A15:E188").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A15").Select

Sheets("FCI").Select
Range("C51").Select

'Copy the data

For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
'Activate the destination worksheet
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
'Select the target range
Range("A15").Select
'Paste in the target destination
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works, The problem i'm facing now is that The second line is set to indicate that any existing data that's on "Sheet1" should be deleted, and after that it just takes "Sheet1" as the active sheet instead of the sheet I want it to get data from

Answer (score 0):

as I understand by your code, you want to be able to copy data from any active sheet to FSI Sheet. if this is the case , I have done changes as in below code.

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()

temp = ActiveSheet.Index

Sheets(temp).Select
Range("A15:E188").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A15").Select

'Sheets("FCI").Select
'ActiveSheet.Range("C51").Select

'Copy the data

'For k = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
Worksheets(temp).Activate
Sheets(temp).Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
'Activate the destination worksheet
Sheets(temp).Activate
'Select the target range
Range("A15").Select
'Paste in the target destination
Sheets("FCI").Select
Range("A15").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
'Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I want to copy data from the "FCI" sheet to "Sheet1", I have 5 sheets in total that I want to copy from and paste their data on "Sheet1"..."FCI" is just one of those sheets I want to copy data from. Thanks